# trying to run emulator on eclipse

Tags: android

Iam having a problem everytime I try to tun my eclipse it gives an error saying  "Launching new_configuration has encountered a problem" . I have reinstalled several times and tried go-ogling  for solutions

Comment: What OS is it running on (OSX, Linux...)? need more info if you want to get help

Comment: You need to give much more details to make it possible to answer this. What versions are involved? Exact error messages? Everything up to date?

Comment: Does emulator work from command line?

Answer (score 0):

Open the Android Virtual Device Manager (icon with Droid in phone display) and check the icons on the left, they indicate whether your AVD configuration is valid. Also, you may launch your emulator from here ("Start...")

Comment: its running on windows 7 64bit and I Installed the latest ADT bundle from android developers site.